# jqGrid formatter and sortable column - doesn't sort

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using a custom formatter for my jqGrid columnModel and I can't get sorting to work with formatter functions.  If I remove formatter column sorts normally.

```
jQuery("#listAgentOptions").jqGrid({
    height: 240,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: [' ', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Role'],
    colModel: [
    { name: 'status', index: 'status', width: 18, sorttype: 'text', align: 'center', formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return cellvalue == 1 ? "<img src='images/agent_green_s.png' alt='Ready' title='Ready' />" :
        cellvalue == 3 ? "<img src='images/agent_red_s.png' alt='Busy' title='Busy' />" :
        "<img src='images/agent_orange_s.png' alt='Pending Ready' title='Pending Ready' />";
    },
        unformat:
    function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.1).toString(); }
    },
    { name: 'firstName', index: 'firstName', width: 92 },
    { name: 'lastName', index: 'lastName', width: 142 },
    { name: 'role', index: 'role', sorttype: 'int', width: 36, align: 'center', formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return cellvalue == true ? "<img src='images/user_gray.png' alt='Supervisor' title='Supervisor' />" : "<img src='images/user.png' alt='Agent' title='Agent' />";
    }, unformat:
    function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return cellvalue; }
    }
    ],
    sortname: 'lastName'
});
```

Rows are added like this:

```
jQuery("#listAgentOptions").jqGrid('clearGridData');
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
    if (item.ContactType == 1) {
        jQuery("#listAgentOptions").jqGrid('addRowData', i+1, { firstName: item.ContactName.split(" ")[0], lastName: item.ContactName.split(" ")[1],
        role: item.IsSupervisor,
        status: item.Status == "Ready" ? 1 : item.Status == "Busy" ? 3 : 2
        });
    }
});
```

How do I get sorting to work properly?

**Update.** I have just downloaded the latest version of jqGrid - same issue.

I have also tried using `unformat: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { }` but cellvalue is empty there :-E When I use `return Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.1).toString();` it does sort things randomly (each time I click), but `return cellvalue;` just returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have figured out what's going on.

First of all you have to use `unformat` to pass the initial value back to jqGrid sort function.

jqGrid is passing `$(row).text()` to `unformat` function, which for cells with just an html tag returns an empty string, and there is no option to change it. However, what you can do is use the third parameter of `unformat` function, which in my case is `rowObject`. You can then retrieve the actual cell value by using `$(rowObject).html()` and parse it back to the value. Sorting will now work.

Another thing to remember is that if you are using `sorrtype: 'int'` you will have to return integer as a string, like `return '1';`.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, jqGrid uses `unformat` to get the value of the cell:

```
        $.each(ts.rows, function(index, row) {
            try { sv = $.unformat($(row).children('td').eq(col),{rowId:row.id, colModel:ts.p.colModel[col]},col,true);}
            catch (_) { sv = $(row).children('td').eq(col).text(); }
            row.sortKey = findSortKey(sv);
            rows[index] = this;
        });
```

A cell value is then parsed using the handler for the column's `sorttype`, in the case of int:

```
            findSortKey = function($cell) {
                return IntNum($cell.replace(stripNum, ''),0);
            };
```

So basically, if your `unformat` function returns the correct integer for each cell, I would expect column sorting to work as well. If you are still having problems, please post your full code, including the contents of `unformat`.

Comment: Yes, but cellvalue that gets passed to unformat is empty for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It can be your problem is not where you are searching for.

What kind of data holding you use in the jqGrid? I mean the value of parameter **datatype**. If you load the jqGrid data from server, server receive the sorting information from the client and server must give sorted data back. Formatter used only to display data how you prefer. **Client-side sorting** work for example with `datatype: 'xmlstring'` and `datatype: "clientSide"`, but not with `dataType:"xml"` or `dataType:"json"` and `dataType:"jsonp"`. Parameters like `sorttype` works only with client-side sorting and will be ignored with **server-side sorting**. The main role: if you have to define **url** parameter of jqGrid, use use server-side sorting.

Comment: You wrote to less information in your question. Could you post a code of the jqGrid. Then one could reproduce and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug using Firebug and check what the server is receiving. Use `sortable: true`.

By the way, the `sorttype` parameter works only locally (`datatype: local`).

Comment: There is no server, it is sorting an array.