# jqGrid: sorting not working, have specified index, sortable, sorttype in colmodel

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

Not sure if I have missed an option but I am not able to sort my jqGrid with the following code. My grid just has one column which I am trying to make sortable:

```
$('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
                    url: contextPath + '/js/jqgrid-data.json',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    colNames: ['Destination Name'],
                    colModel: [
                        {   name: 'DestName',
                            sortable: true,
                            sorttype: 'text',
                            index: 'DestName'
                        }
                    ],
                    sortname: 'DestName',
                    sortorder: 'asc',
                    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 600,
                    onSelectRow: function(id){
                        alert('Selected row ID ' + id);
                    }
                });
```

The data from the server looks like this:

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 10,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "DestName": "Administration Office"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "DestName": "Business Office"
        }
....
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server is responsible for sorting, not jqgrid. Options are specified to jqgrid so that it would pass the correct params to server. So you should catch `sord` and `sidx` params (for sorting direction and sorting field) on server side, and sort there.

Comment: I found this Stackoverflow link useful too: [jqGrid sorting discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756521/jqgrid-formatter-and-sortable-column-doesnt-sort)